# Profiling tools for client side optimization

Tags: optimization, cross-browser, profiling, client-side

I have to perform a client side optimization for our site (server side on Java). 
Yesterday I read some articles about it and create a plan how to do it:

1. Find tool for profiling the site to see the effect of optimization
2. Perform the optimization

Could you please suggest some tools for profiling web-sites and some useful articles about that?
I found a lot of articles about optimization itself, but about profiling nothing useful.

**edit:** any automated solutions will be good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some info that helps start from scratch if you are new one in client side profiling/benchmarking.

[Chrome DevTools](http://www.igvita.com/slides/2012/devtools-tips-and-tricks/#1) presentation by Ilya Grigorik, very interesting and useful.

[Speed tracer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/?csw=1) is another useful tool for benchmarking (as well Chrome Extension).

Answer (score 1):

Just came across [speedcurve.com](http://speedcurve.com) not sure how well it works but it looks very promising.